# Check for an array element in a string

Tags: javascript

I've been doing "check string in array", but never the oposite. And that's what I need now. Currently I have this:

```
var Hash = 'http://example.com/place/england,
    arr = ['/place/'];

if(Hash.indexOf(arr)) {
    alert('it is')
} else {
    alert('it is not')
};
```

Problem is, it always returns true (alerts `it is`). Where I go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the array to compare. Second thing your condition is not written in desired way.

```
if(Hash.indexOf(arr))
```

`.indexOf()` gives `-1` for not found else `> -1`. In js `0` is `false` and other numbers are `true` hence you always get the true alert.

```js
var Hash = 'http://example.com/place/england',
  arr = ['/place/'];
var i = arr.length;
while (i--)
  if (-1 < Hash.indexOf(arr[i]))
    alert('found, ' + arr[i]);
  else
    alert('not found, ' + arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` when not found, `0...n-1` on found. Thus, you are saying `it is` when `['/place/'].toString()` (which evaluates to `/place/`) is *not at the start of the string*; you will get `it is not` only if it was found at the nullth position.

Instead, you want to test for `-1`. Also, if you want to test for all elements of the array instead of the concatenation of the array (because, if `arr = ['/place/', '/time/']` you would end up searching for the string `"/place/,/time/"`), you want to do something else, like iteration or regular expression.

```
// iteration (functional style)
var found = arr.some(function(element) { return Hash.indexOf(element) !== -1; });
```

or

```
// regular expression approach
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}
var pattern = new RegExp(arr.map(escapeRegExp).join('|'));
var found = pattern.test(Hash);
```

(`escapeRegExp` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters))

Answer (score 0):

Well [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) only accepts a string as an argument, and you're passing it an array. Either access the first element of the array, to get the string, or loop over the whole array if it could have more than one element.

```
if(Hash.indexOf(arr[0])) {
//                 ^^^ access first element
```

Or loop the whole array:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(Hash.indexOf(arr[i])) {
        alert('it is')
    } else {
        alert('it is not')
    };
}
```